# PrimeFaces DataTable row coloring not working

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, xhtml, datatables

I want to Change the color of a row based on the status column.
I have looked at the example on the primefaces website
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableColoring.jsf
and looked up examples online but I cant seem to get it working with my code.
The problem is it is highlighting everything rather than just the rows where the status is set to 'Closed'

here is my code

```
<p:dataTable id="ComplaintTable" var="complainer"
                    rowKey="#{complainer.id}"
                    selection="#{bigComplaintsDAO.selectedComplaintRow}"
                    widgetVar="complaintsTableSearch"
                    paginator="True" rows="15" 
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="15,20,30,40,50,100"
                    resizableColumns="true"
                    filteredValue="#{bigComplaintsDAO.filteredComplaintRow}"
                    selectionMode="single" value="#{bigComplaintsDAO.complaintList}"
                    style="font-size:10px;width:100%;"
                    rowStyleClass="#{(complaint.status) eq Closed ? 'Closed' : null}">
```

and the CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
            .Closed 
            {
                background-color: #6CE26C !important;
                background-image: none !important;
                color: #000000 !important;
            }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!
I changed my code to

```
rowStyleClass="#{(complainer.status) eq 'Closed' ? 'Closed' : null}"
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, rowStyleClass did not work if the datatable was placed within a p:panelGrid.
I switched to a p:panel and then it worked.

Comment: Sure that the rowStyleClass was not applied (independent of the css selwctpr working or not)? I see no reason a panelGrid would break things

Comment: Yes Sir I am sure. If I tried to set the style in a column it worked correctly. Then I only changed the container from panelGrid to panel and it worked fine. Very weird. If you need details about the versions I use let me know.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the following code worked:

**DataTable (HTML)**

```
<p-dataTable [rowStyleClass]="getRowClass">
```

**Component (TS)**

```
  getRowClass() {
    return 'my-new-class';
  }
```

Comment: This is not PrimeFaces but PrimeNG